# В папку assets попадает старая версия jquery-ui

Tags: jquery, yii, jquery-ui

На страницах присутствуют компоненты из библиотеки UI в самой странице в секции заголовка прописана новая библиотека `jQuery` но при входе на страницу в каталоге `/assets` появляется папка с старой версией файла `jquery-ui.min.js` . Мне надо что бы эти компоненты были из новой версии jQuery-ui. Мне кажется что вручную подкладывать новую версию библиотеки в динамический каталог как то неправильно будет. Как исправить всю эту ситуацию, что бы компоненты использовали статически лежащую библиотеку на своем хостинге?

PS

все это происходит под управлением yii1

Answer (score 0):

Можно переопределить какие библиотеки подгружать.

где то в начале страницы:

```
<?php
    $cs=Yii::app()->clientScript;
        $cs->scriptMap=array(
                'jquery.js' => '/js/jquery.js',
                'jquery.min.js' => '/js/jquery.min.js',
                'jquery-ui.js' => '/js/jquery-ui.min.js',
                'jquery-ui.min.js' => '/js/jquery-ui.min.js'
        );
?>
```

в папке js своего сервера лежат указанные файлы

возможно это можно сделать в конфиге yii но я не знаю как